# Swift Stepper Action that changes UITextField and UILabel within same cell

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistepper

I am using a function to build my custom cell. the function used to create the cell is "makeMyList". The stepper I have successfully increments and decrements the itemQuantity textField. The trouble I am having comes with updating the "itemPrice" label. I want itemPrice.text to be quantity * price and update dynamically as the quantity either goes up or down dynamically.

Could someone possibly help me with how to get this to happen?

Thank you in advance!

```
class MyListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var itemPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

    @IBAction func itemQuantityStepper(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        self.itemQuantity.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func makeMyList(myItem: MyList)
    {
        self.itemName.text = myItem.MyItemName
        self.itemPrice.text = String(stepper.value * Double(myItem.MyItemPrice))
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply update `itemPrice.text` in the `itemQuantityStepper` function.

Comment: @rmaddy I have tried that. itemQuantityStepper cannot take (myItem: MyList) as a parameter. So in doing that the value only increments. if attempting to decrement, it stays at the previously incremented value.

Comment: Save a reference to the `MyList` or its price as an instance variable. Then you can reference that in the `itemQuantityStepper` method.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you possibly elaborate on that a little bit. possibly point me to, or show me an small example code snippet?

Comment: @rmaddy after reading what you said a million times over, I finally realized what you meant and fixed my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same issue. Here is the answer to my own question.

Hope it helps!

```
class MyListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var itemPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemQuantity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

    var price: Float = 0.0
    var quantity: Int = 1


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func makeMyList(myItem: MyList)
    {
        self.itemName.text = myItem.MyItemName
        self.itemPrice.text = myItem.MyItemPrice

        price = Float(myItem.MyItemPrice)
    }

    @IBAction func itemQuantityStepper(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        quantity = Int(sender.value)
        self.itemQuantity.text = String(quantity)
        self.itemPrice.text = price * Float(quantity)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```