# Swift - Stepper in TableViewCell - Action not Responding

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, ibaction, uistepper

Another Swift beginner here. I have a Stepper in a TableView cell which needs to update a label in the same cell. I got part of the way there by asking another question and I received a great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42877313/3692615.

I think I understand how the code is supposed to work, and my label is updating with the initial value, but unfortunately the stepper action doesn't seem to be connected properly.

I have tried:

1. Making sure I do not have redundant outlets in the connections inspector
2. Clean/Build project
3. Delete all outlets completely and reconnect
4. Tried changing the sender on the stepper action from UIStepper to AnyObject

I'm running out of ideas. Here is a screenshot of the connections inspector.
[image]

Here is the logic. Its basically a model class at the top. Then the outlets along with a property 'buyStat' to hold the current data source item and to update the stepper and label when buyStat is set. That's all working, but the stepper action below it is not. I can't get "stepper working" to print.

[image]

Then if it helps, here is my ViewController class

[image]

If anyone notices anything or has another idea for me to troubleshoot it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've disabled the user interaction in your cell for row at index method:

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
```

You should remove this line.

Comment: Aha! Thank you sir. That would seem to be the problem.